# printing one record from array errors out?

Tags: php, arrays, printing, associative-array

I am tring to pull one record out of an array and keep getting "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"  What am I doing wrong?

The array is trxnResult.  I am trying to print as:

```
  print $trxnResult['Bank_Resp_code'];
```

Here is a snippet of the dump:

```
        stdClass Object ( [ExactID] => xxxxx [Password] => [Transaction_Type] => 00 [DollarAmount] => 69.0 [SurchargeAmount] => [Card_Number] => ############1111 [Transaction_Tag] => 152425718 [Track1] => [Track2] => [PAN] => [Authorization_Num] => [Expiry_Date] => 1213 [CardHoldersName] => fdfd [VerificationStr1] => [VerificationStr2] => [CVD_Presence_Ind] => 0 [ZipCode] => [Tax1Amount] => [Tax1Number] => [Tax2Amount] => [Tax2Number] => [Secure_AuthRequired] => [Secure_AuthResult] => [Ecommerce_Flag] => [XID] => [CAVV] => [CAVV_Algorithm] => [Reference_No] => [Customer_Ref] => [Reference_3] => [Language] => [Client_IP] => 198.57.135.205 [Client_Email] => dfdf [User_Name] => [Currency] => USD [PartialRedemption] => [TransarmorToken] => [CardType] => Visa [EAN] => [VirtualCard] => [CardCost] => [Transaction_Error] => [Transaction_Approved] => [EXact_Resp_Code] => 00 [EXact_Message] => Transaction Normal [Bank_Resp_Code] => 201
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are considering an object as an array.

Here is the solution:

`print $trxnResult->Bank_Resp_code;`

Comment: You should remove the trailing `'`